# Pulling in related entities via Breeze for a single entity using fetchEntityByKey into Knockout observable

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm trying to pull a single Breeze entity and its related entities into a KnockOut observable object (not an array) with child KO observableArrays (for one to many relationships).  I can't work out how to do this with fetchEntitybyKey - I can do it using an entityQuery with a predicate, but then it requires an observableArray (which makes subsequent coding harder and the markup more complex).

Does anyone have a code example of doing this?

Many thanks
Jeremy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use fetchEntityById as a convenient way to get the specific entity either from cache or from the remote service. Then the expansion must be done in another query. You will almost always want to do it in two steps anyway because you will want to check if the cached version is all you need before going remote and expanding. That check is not included in the code below, but you would just replace `return refreshProject(p);` with `return p.isPartial() ? refreshProject(p) : projectObservable(p);` so you only refresh if the entity has been marked as a partial entity or one that needs refreshing for some other reason. You must, of course, implement the logic to mark entities as partial.

```
var getProjectById = function (projectId, projectObservable) {
    // fetchEntityByKey will look in local cache first (because 3rd 
    // parm is true) and if not there then it will go remote
    return manager.fetchEntityByKey(
        'Project', projectId, true)
        .then(fetchSucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    // Refresh the entity from remote store
    function fetchSucceeded(data) {
        var p = data.entity;
        return refreshProject(p);
    }

    function refreshProject(project) {
        // fromEntities(someEntity) creates a query that gets only someEntity
        // from the remote service.
        return EntityQuery.fromEntities(project)
            .expand('navigationProp1.complexProp1,' +
                'navigationProp1.complexProp2,' +
                'navigationProp2.complexProp1,' +
                'navigationProp2.complexProp2')
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
    }

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var p = data.results[0];
        return projectObservable(p);
    }
};
```

The `expand` clause is quite interesting because you might have a navigation property such as contracts, which is a list of all contracts for a project. If a contract contains only primitive data types you can just expand with `.expand('contracts')` but if the contract type has one or more complex properties such as a supplier (including various supplier details) then expanding just for contracts will only bring in the Id of the supplier. The syntax is interesting because there is no such property as `contracts.supplier`, but you tell Breeze to include all the properties of the supplier on each contract with `expand('contracts.supplier')`.

Comment: Excellent - thank you david004 that solved my problem and showed me how to work with the cache, and pointed me towards using partial entities (for which HotTowel has example code).